# How to use dash (-) as value for criteria

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I don't know if this is possible in MS Access, but what I want to do is detect dash (-) and use Between in SQL statement and or Comma.

Ex. I have a table called "Books" with fields: BookID, Title, Subject.

Now how can I query Books table that allows a user to input a value in a textbox like:

```
1 or 1-5 or 1,3,4.
```

If the value is 1 the sql statement should be:

```
SELECT * FROM Books WHERE BookID = 1
```

If the value of 1-5 then the sql statement should be:

```
SELECT * FROM Books WHERE BookID BETWEEN 1 And 5
```

If the value of 1,3,4 then the sql statement should be:

```
SELECT * FROM Books WHERE BookID IN (1,3,4)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cut from something I already have;

```
s = "SELECT * FROM Books WHERE BookID" & parseSarg("11,22,33")
```

using;

```
Public Function parseSarg(str As String) As String
    Dim re As Object: Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    re.Global = True
    Select Case True
        '//is number
        Case reTest(re, "^\d+$", str):          parseSarg = " = " & str
        '//is number-number
        Case reTest(re, "^\d+-\d+$", str):      parseSarg = " BETWEEN " & Replace$(str, "-", " AND ")
        '//is number,number[,number]
        Case reTest(re, "^\d+(?:,\d+)*$", str): parseSarg = " IN (" & str & ")"
        '//is >number
        Case reTest(re, "^>\s*\d+$", str):      parseSarg = " >" & Mid$(str, 2)
        Case Else
            parseSarg = " = 0 AND 1=0"
    End Select
End Function

Function reTest(re As Object, pattern As String, value As String) As Boolean
    re.pattern = pattern
    reTest = re.Test(value)
End Function
```

Comment: Its coming from a textbox in access so a VBA hook should be ok

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Books.Title FROM Books WHERE Books.BookID > 1 AND Books.BookID < 5;
```

Comment: hi, the value must come from a textbox. only one textbox.